# Key Binding M1+Z not working in Eclipse E4 Application

Tags: eclipse-rcp, e4

I'm developing a Eclipse E4 RCP application with RCP Oxygen and are currently implementing undo/redo functionality.

So I have an undo command and a key binding for the undo command:

```
<bindings xmi:id="_hkeOkBZjEeipCZp77ICVOQ" elementId="" keySequence="M1+Z" command="__4gqQBZiEeipCZp77ICVOQ">
  <tags>type:user</tags>
</bindings>
```

The problem is that the shortcut is not displayed in the menu item, but the binding itself works. If I change the binding to M1+I, the shortcut is displayed. It seems to me like a bug.

Does anyone else have this behavior and knows a solution or workaround?

Answer (score 2):

I am using Version: Oxygen Release (4.7.0), Build id: 20170620-1800

Menu shortcut seems to be working for me
[image]

Application.e4xmi config is like below

[image]